# Why session is not null after session.invalidate() in JAVA?

Tags: java, session, invalidation

I am facing very strange problem while developing JavaEE WEB Application.

Even after invalidating the `HttpSession` using `session.invalidate();`, I am not getting session `null`. There is a case where I have one statement in execution like below after invalidating session.

```
if (null != session && null != session.getAttribute("loginToken")){
   //do something
}
```

I am not getting session null here so second condition will try to execute. And hence session is not null, so I am getting `IllegalStateException` - `session is already invalidated`. But why session is not null after invalidating it?? :(

Comment: Why would it be `null`? It's just invalid.

Comment: void invalidate()

    Invalidates this session then unbinds any objects bound to it.

    Throws:
        IllegalStateException - if this method is called on an already invalidated session

java docs : http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#invalidate%28%29

Comment: A variable is not `null` unless you set it to null, no matter what method you call on it, it can't make it `null`.

Answer (score 18):

Calling `session.invalidate()` removes the session from the registry. Calling  `getSession(false)` afterwards will return null (note that `getSession()` or `getSession(true)` will create a new session in this case, see [HttpServletRequest API](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession-boolean-)). Calling `invalidate()` will also remove all session attributes bound to the session. However if your code still has references to the session or any of its attributes then these will still be accessible:

```
    // create session if none exists (default) and obtain reference
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();

    // add a session attribute
    session.setAttribute("lollypop", "it's my party");

    // obtain reference to session attribute 
    Object lollypop = session.getAttribute("lollypop");

    // print session ID and attribute
    System.out.println(session.getId());
    System.out.println(lollypop);

    session.invalidate();

    // session invalidated but reference to it still exists
    if (session == null) {            
        System.out.println("This will never happen!");
    }

    // print ID from invalidated session and previously obtained attribute (will be same as before)
    System.out.println(session.getId());
    System.out.println(lollypop);

    // print 'null' (create=false makes sure no new session is created)
    System.out.println(request.getSession(false));
```

Example output:

```
1k47acjdelzeinpcbtczf2o9t
it's my party
1k47acjdelzeinpcbtczf2o9t
it's my party
null
```

So far for the explanation. To solve your problem you should do:

```
HttpSession existingSession = request.getSession(false);
if (existingSession != null && existingSession.getAttribute("loginToken") != null){
   //do something
}
```

Comment: I am using `request.getSession(false);` still getting same problem. :(

Comment: If you call request.getSession().invalidate() and directly afterwards in the same thread request.getSession(false) it should return null. If not, please show us the exact code and the stacktrace/result you see.

Comment: I am also using request.getSession(false); still getting same problem. did you get solution for this?

Comment: @SwatiThakare If it's still the initial misconception that the variable pointing to the session will magically become null after calling session.invalidate() I suggest you re-read the comments and answers on this page. If it's something else, please post a new question.

Answer (score 4):

The invalidate method does the following (from [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#invalidate%28%29)):

`Invalidates this session then unbinds any objects bound to it.`

It says nothing about the `HttpSession`-object itself, but invalidates the session's variables. If you call a method of a class, it is impossible for the object to be `null` after  that method call. If your session should be null afterwards, the method must include a line that looks something like: `this = null;` which would not be possible. Throwing an exception for an invalidated session is the prefered way to do it.

Comment: This is plain nonsense, you cannot assign anything to `this` !

Comment: Now better, but I think it is still confusing to say that is "highly unlikely" that an object reference becomes `null` after an method invocation on it - it is impossible in Java!

Comment: @GyroGearless Missed it, re-read the text and everything should be consistent now. Thank you for your input! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try passing false as the parameter to the getSession(boolean) . This will give back a session if it exists or else it will return null.

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
if(session==null || !request.isRequestedSessionIdValid() )
{
    //comes here when session is invalid.

}
```