# reload jsp page after logout on back button click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jsp

In every page of mine, there is a logout option. When the user clicks this logout option, they get log out `session.invalidate();` .When I press the back button, even if the session is invalidated, I get the previous page with all the contents in the input tag.How can I resolve this problem.I tried `window.location.reload()`,and many other options, but it's not working in here.\
[My website](http://onlineddservices.com/) is this. and credentials are. `test123@gmail.com` and pass is `Amal123`

Comment: try `window.location.href = '/'` you should be referenced to reload the page in the base path of the domain

Comment: page is reloading infinitely.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent user from seeing previously visited secured page after logout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194207/prevent-user-from-seeing-previously-visited-secured-page-after-logout)

Comment: How can I do this same purpose in PHPalso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can copy and paste this code in every page of your site which clears the cached page.

```
 <%
response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-store");
response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache");
response.setDateHeader ("Expires", 0);

if(session.getAttribute("some_token")==null)
  response.sendRedirect("login/login.html");

%>
```

In logout you must be invalidating session so when you click back it would check the `some_token` attribute value in `session` and if not there it will redirect you to `login` page . But remember after login you are setting `some_token` attribute in session.

Comment: happy to helped you! :)

Comment: I set everything previously except no-store and it wasn't working. The no-store helped. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Before all pages you want to open only when session is active you have to put a filter that checks for session before your pages get open.

And on loguot you have to invalidate the current session.

And then your will be able to press back button but can not perform any funtionality

Comment: I don't want to see that page again after logout. I am checking whether the session is null or not, if it is null, it will be redirected to login page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a session attribute... for example when you log in, set a variable value to username e.g:
HTML

```
<form name="login" action="/login.jsp" method="post" >
    <input type="text" name="username" >
    <input type="password" name="password" >
<input type="submit" >
```

JSP:

```
String userName=request.getParameter("username");
request.getSession().setAttribute("username",userName);
```

Now On every page,add this code

`<% if(request.getSession().getAttribute("username")==null)
    response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");%>`

Also, at the time of logout do not forget to remove the session attribute.

```
request.getSession().removeAttribute("username");
```

Try it and let me know.

Comment: at logout, the session is already invalidated,why should i remove the attribute again? Also in every page iam checking whether session is null , it null it will be redirected to login page. for every time checking, the page needs to be reloaded.

Comment: Same problem in this question,  check the answers... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24677949/why-session-is-not-null-after-session-invalidate-in-java

Comment: For this i have to reload the page again. Please check the question.