# how to clear value of JSESSIONID cookie?

Tags: java, session, tomcat, cookies, session-cookies

My application uses a different platform to manage authentication. hence we are not using tomcat's default JSESSIONID cookie for any session management.
I do not see in our code that we call request.getSession() explicitly.
However, the response that goes back to browser has JSESSIONID cookie in Response Headers.
Because of which, when user clicks on logout, the JSESSIONID cookie value is not cleared off as authentication is managed by a different app. So, user can still intercept and fetch data using this cookie causing a risk.

Please help.

I tried creating a new JSESSIONID cookie and setting maxAge = 0 for that JSESSIONID to overwrite the existing one but did not work.

I want to either stop the application from generating this cookie or stop sending the value in response headers so its value is not accessible by other users.

Comment: Are you using Spring?

Comment: If this application doesn’t use the session, how can the session cookie be used to intercept and fetch data?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why session is not null after session.invalidate() in JAVA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24677949/why-session-is-not-null-after-session-invalidate-in-java)

Comment: @Unmitigated Yes using spring

Comment: @Tim Moore Its not using JSESSIONID. It uses an external API to authenticate and return data if session is still valid

Comment: Olaf Kock, not exactly, we are not trying to invalidate session here

Comment: @user3494187 the question says “ So, user can still intercept and fetch data using this cookie causing a risk.” If the session isn’t used, there should be no data to fetch.

Comment: @TimMoore do you know anyway we can stop sending jsessionid neither in cookie nor in the url in response?